# typo3 realurl - how to rewrite a get-parameter

Tags: typo3, realurl

I want to rewrite a url with realurl - I#Ve got a url in this form: ".../anzeige/?bildId=1&cHash=b90ddb3f161bc8c3f5113a3b823794d0". want to rewrite the bildId=1 into something like this: Rose.html - There is an Mysql-Table with ste uid = 1 and a field "Blume" in line 1: "Rose.
Is there any possibility to rewrie it?

Thank you
Volker

Answer (score 0):

As example for your realurl.conf:

```
'postVarSets' => [
  '_DEFAULT' => [
    'banner' => [
      [
        'GETvar'      => 'bildId',
        'lookUpTable' => [
          'table'               => 'tablename',
          'id_field'            => 'uid',
          'alias_field'         => 'title',
          'addWhereClause'      => ' AND NOT deleted',
          'useUniqueCache'      => 1,
          'useUniqueCache_conf' => [
            'strtolower'     => 1,
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
          ],
          'autoUpdate'          => 1,
          'expireDays'          => 180,
        ],
      ],
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: ok :) Thank you very much for your help :)
I'tried it - I wrote this in my real_autoconf.php, renamed it too realurl_conf.php ans in in extensionmanager i disabled automatic configuration. Nothing happens - where is the problem? :(

Comment: Maybe some cache is active so you need to clear the caches. Also the links could be saved into the realurl internal cache tables.

Comment: Otherwsie, please provide your current configuration, to check.